# Converting specical characters in XML stream

Tags: xml, string, mfc

I have an XML stream which contains special characters such ' stored in a CString object. Is there any method other than replacing individual characters in the stream to convert these special characters ?

Comment: For example apostrophe needs to be converted to &apos;

Answer (score 3):

The only characters that need escaping are " < > &.

But I would recommend the use a standard XML library.
That would not only take care of escaping, but a lot of other problems (encoding, entities, validation, etc.)

Comment: I couldn't agree more, the chances of getting everything 100% right all the time when rolling your own XML routines are slim. I have to deal all the time with people who have decided to roll their own XML routines and they almost always end up creating incorrectly formed XML in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I frankly don't see another option.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, install a filter in the writer. This allows you to write the stream char by char and replace the special characters when you encounter them (saving you from having to allocate a second string object).

Try to output as many characters of the string at once as possible because calling write() in a loop for every single character is expensive. Instead use this pseudo code:

```
int start = 0;
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.getChar(i);
    String emit = null;
    switch (c) {
    case '<': emit = "&lt;"; break;
    case '>': emit = "&gt;"; break;
    case '\'': emit = "&apos;"; break;
    case '"': emit = "&quot;"; break;
    }
    if (emit != null) {
        write(str,start,i);
        start = i;
        write(emit);
    }
}
if (start != str.length()) {
    write(str);
}
```

In the common case, the loop will traverse the string once (which is fast) and call write() once.

If you can't install a filter in the writer, you can use the same code to filter the string. In the common case, you will simply return the input string. In the `if (emit != null)`, you can then allocate a new copy. But since this will only happen if there are special characters in the string, this is much cheaper than creating a copy for every string.